# Preact You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server, preact

Just need some help please I'm losing my mind with this struggle. I've searched a lot of posts of this kind of same issue and it didn't work that's what I'm here asking for help.

I'm currently running simple React on a webpack-dev-server and when I want to establish the preact compat I just get this error:

***You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type on Client.jsx***

This are the files:

**Client.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

const renderClient = () => {
  render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('app'),
  );
};

renderClient();
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const config = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './src/components/Client.jsx',
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public/',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    alias: {
      react: 'preact-compat',
      'react-dom': 'preact-compat',
    },
  },
  devServer: {
    publicPath: '/public/',
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: true,
    chunks: false,
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [path.resolve('js'), path.resolve('node_modules/preact-compat/src')],
      },
    ],
  },
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.devtool = 'source-map';
  config.plugins = [];
}

module.exports = config;
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-react-jsx", { "pragma": "h" }],
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["."],
        "alias": {
          "react": "preact-compat",
          "react-dom": "preact-compat"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "presets": [
    "react",
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": "last 2 versions"
        },
        "loose": true,
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.jsx` rule you only include files in the directories `./js/` and `./node_modules/preact-compat/src/`, but your entry is `./src/components/Client.jsx` and therefore Babel is not applied to it. You would also need to add the `./src/` files to the rule.

The `path.resolve('js')` should probably have been `path.resolve('src')`, unless you have a `./js/` directory that is used from your code. Additionally, the `preact-compat/src` is unnecessary, since it ships an already transpiled code, that will be used when you import `preact-compat`.

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  include: [path.resolve('src')],
},
```

Instead of only including what you need to transpile, you could exclude everything you *don't* want to transpile. That would usually be `node_modules` as you've done in your ESLint rule.

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules/,
},
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro!

Answer (score 0):

You missed a loader that will manipulate `jsx`.
If you are using Babel you can use babel-loader for transforming jsx into js.

you can add that loader to your `webpack.config.js` file

```
var config = {
    // Existing Code ....
    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test : /\.jsx?/,
                include : APP_DIR,
                loader : 'babel'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I've flagged this as not an answer. The problem with referencing links is that when/if they die this is useless to future readers. I suggest copying the relevant details from that link and referencing it instead, so at least if it goes away there is still an answer to the question.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work, its still saying the same error